# URL clear on button click in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a great problem in an Apex project. On the main page I added a dynamic action on double click which generates URL like: `f?p=App:Page:Session::::itemNames:itemValues:` and goes to a page with this URL. On that subpage I have a button that clear all of the item's values. I want also to clear the subpage's URL from the values, and get something like: `f?p=App:Page:Session::::::`. I've tried to clear cache at different levels but it didn't affect on the URL itself.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'm not sure what you've attempted, or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to change URL of the page in the browser from: www.myapecapp.com/f?p=App:Page:Session::::itemNames:itemValues: to: www.myapecapp.com/f?p=App:Page:Session:::::: on the buton click in Apex without using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all the items on a page with a URL similar to this:

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=APP:PAGE:SESSION:::PAGES_TO_CLEAR::
```

The **PAGES_TO_CLEAR** text in the URL above should be substituted with the pages you want to clear all items from separated by commas. As an example, the URL below would navigate to page 1, but clear all the page items on page 4 and 5

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:103732008363447:::4,5::
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I want to do. I just want to change the URL of my website on button click from: `www.myapexapp.com/f?p=App:Page:Session::::itemNames:itemValues:` to: `www.myapexapp.com/f?p=App:Page:Session::::::`. Clearing items doesn't change the URL.

Comment: how is it that you are building the URL for the button click?

Comment: It's like: on the main page I create the URL with items' values that are passed to the subpage. On the subpage I clear those items' values but the URL still contains that passed values. So on the subpage refresh I still have items with previously cleared values because the browser use the URL that I had created before.

Comment: You cannot change the URL that appears in a browser's address without navigating to that page, even with Javascript.

Comment: in JS it's easy to change the URL using: window.history.pushState()